# Prompting for SAS ODBC connection password when running in batch mode

Tags: sas

For various reasons I prefer to run my SAS programs in batch mode as much a possible.  And for security reasons I'd prefer to have SAS prompt me for a password whenever making and ODBC connection to a Teredata warehouse.  Can I have both of these things at once?

The following code works fine when run from SAS interactively, but won't create a prompt when run in batch.

```
proc sql;
    connect to odbc (prompt);
quit;
```

Anyone know of a way make this work?  (Also, I'm looking for a solution specifically using the `connect` statement; SAS/ACCESS `libname` methods of reaching the Teradata aren't available to me.)

Comment: Can't remember if something kludgy like %window statement might work in batch.  I think it might allow you to get a very simple prompt, then enter in some values.  Depending on your environment, there are probably other alternative approaches.  SAS server with metadata has lots.  Even on Windows, could consider storing connection info in a .txt file that only you can access.  Sometimes PWENCODE is enough to make people feel safe...

Comment: `%window` works in batch, but once it gets its interaction from the user it disappears again, so the odbc command comming after it still fails.  I haven't found any sort of "hold-open" trick for it...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that it's possible to have a batch program prompt you.  However, you could solve the problem by making the password (or any part of the connection string or the whole string) a parameter you pass to SAS when you run the batch program, using `SYSPARM`.

Then you can type the password in the command line when you execute the program.  You could easily do something like include a "%1" parameter in your normal "run SAS batch" program, or write a custom one for this use case.

If you like to run things by right-click menu run, you could solve it by writing a VB Script or a Powershell script (Windows), or a similar script in Unix, that opens a prompt window (via the OS) to get the parameter, then runs the program in batch (and then add that to the right-click menu).

Comment: The nice thing about the code in my question is that it doesn't end up printing the password to the log or anywhere else.  That's really what I want it for.

Comment: Also, 99% of the time I run SAS via a command line written and submitted by a little vim plugin I wrote -- so solutions that require a little scripting are A-OK.

Comment: I think if you pass it by &SYSPARM and you don't have SYMBOLGEN on, it shouldn't print the password to the log.  But I always use credential-based authentication nowadays so I guess I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: On the other hand, you could also create an ODBC connection in the OS and then refer to that ODBC connection by name (so the credentials are saved, but in a relatively secure location intended for that purpose).