# Run sas code in unix-putty using command line variable

Tags: sas, sh, command-line-arguments, command-prompt, putty

Usually, I run SAS code using UNIX-putty using command **nohup sas cr_test.sas&** 
But, now I want to change it to as dynamic by passing variables from command line in unix. 
I have less knowledge of unix-putty.
could anyone please help me out how I can make my code more dynamic. I am going to mention as an example and logic.

**As an Example:** I want to pass **User ID** and **Password** from command line.
i want to share the logic what i want to do. 
*logic:* I changed SAS code. i replaced user id by &1 and password by &2. 
then pass these user id and password from command line as **nohup sas ct_test.sas& id password**.
Screen of SAS code in which i changed &1 and &2 in the Proc sql. 
[image]
 Unix-Putty code in which i am trying to pass command line variables for id as &1 and password &2.
[image]

please reply and help me out.

Comment: Entering passwords via the command line exposes them to anyone who can view /proc - on shared access systems it's usually safer to read them from a file to which only you and root have read access.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prompting for SAS ODBC connection password when running in batch mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30514039/prompting-for-sas-odbc-connection-password-when-running-in-batch-mode)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the command line option -set to create environment variables that you can retrieve in your SAS program.  Syntax is

```
-set id myidvalue
```

Then in your program you can use the `%SYSGET()` macro function to retrieve the value.

```
... user=%sysget(id) ...
```

I wouldn't use it for passwords, but it is useful for passing run time options.

Comment: Thanks Tom. i am using ksh shell. I used **%put user=%sysget(id);** in sas code and **sas test.sas -set id myidvalue** in the command line. but it is showing warning in log as
"WARNING: The argument to macro function %SYSGET is not defined as a system variable.". user field is not showing blank in log. how can i define system variable foe ksh shell? there is any need to define environment variables? if yes could you please suggest how can i define environment variables?

Comment: On a Unix command the options go before the arguments. Or use the -sysin option to specify the program name.

Comment: Thanks Tom. I tried with 'sas test.sas -sysin -set ID myidval' but it is still showing same warning. **WARNING: The argument to macro function %SYSGET is not defined as a system variable.**. if i try to use 'sas -sysin test.sas -set ID myidval' it is showing **invalid option --s**. if possible could you share any working sample code for the same scenario so that i can replicate the logic in my code.